# Python:- Split email from list of emails (comma, space separated)

Tags: python, string, list

My input is

```
email_list = 

"mail1@mail.com,mail2@mail.com, mail3@mail.com mail4@mail.com 
mail5@mail.com"
```

Excepted output is

```
['mail1@mail.com', 'mail2@mail.com', 'mail3@mail.com', 'mail4@mail.com', 'mail5@mail.com']
```

I tried this method, but it will split only (,) separated. please let me know.

```
output = email_list.split(',')
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expression :

```
>>> import re
>>> email_list = "mail1@mail.com,mail2@mail.com, mail3@mail.com mail4@mail.com"
>>> re.split(r'[, ]*',email_list)
['mail1@mail.com', 'mail2@mail.com', 'mail3@mail.com', 'mail4@mail.com']
```

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) split your string based on `r'[, ]*'` that split with any combine of comma (`,`) and space ().

Comment: Very nice, Thanks friend

Comment: if semicolon, newline means what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

Strangely - no one appears to have pointed possibly the most obvious and easiest...

```
>>> email_list = "mail1@mail.com,mail2@mail.com, mail3@mail.com mail4@mail.com"
>>> email_list.replace(',', ' ').split()
['mail1@mail.com', 'mail2@mail.com', 'mail3@mail.com', 'mail4@mail.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex,

```
>>> email_list = "mail1@mail.com,mail2@mail.com, mail3@mail.com mail4@mail.com"
>>> [i for x in email_list.split(',') if x for i in x.split(' ') if i]
['mail1@mail.com', 'mail2@mail.com', 'mail3@mail.com', 'mail4@mail.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Also without regex :)

```
import re
email_list = "mail1@mail.com,mail2@mail.com, mail3@mail.com mail4@mail.com"
print filter(lambda x:x, sum([x.split(",") for x in email_list.split(" ")], []))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
email_list.replace(" ","")
```

Before you use

```
output = email_list.split(',')
```

Comment: It will concatenate `mail3@mail.com` and `mail4@mail.com`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the missing comma, the right way sould be

Comment: email_list = email_list.replace(" ",",").replace(",,",",")

Comment: I think you meant to replace " " with ",".  You should edit the answer.

Comment: @dgsleeps Your second solution won't work if there are `3` spaces between emails.